# cakePHP hasOne empty

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I'm new to cakePHP and I have a Problem with Relations.

My Model Looks like this:

```php
<?
class Operator extends AppModel
{
    var $name = 'Operator';
    var $hasOne = array('Contact','Adress','Land');
}
?>
```

and my Table Looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `operators` (
  `id` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `name` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `adress_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `land_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `contact_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `operator_category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `legal_form` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `affidavit` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `comment` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`),
  KEY `operator_category_fk_idx` (`operator_category_id`),
  KEY `contact_id_idx` (`contact_id`),
  KEY `adress_id_idx` (`adress_id`),
  KEY `land_id_idx` (`land_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `adress_id` FOREIGN KEY (`adress_id`) REFERENCES `adresses` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `contact_id` FOREIGN KEY (`contact_id`) REFERENCES `contacts` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `land_id` FOREIGN KEY (`land_id`) REFERENCES `lands` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `operator_category_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`operator_category_id`) REFERENCES `operator_category` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
```

but cakePHP doesn't Show any data from e.g. contacts
[image]

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: **hasOne** is a rarely used association. In this case, you want use **belongsTo**.

Comment: Are you sure, your `contacts` table have any records?

Comment: @AgRizzo "rarely" is a little exaggerated - less often, perhaps.

Comment: why `belongsTo` in `Operator`? Doesn't a **Contact** belong to a **Operator**?

Comment: A model `X` **belongsTo** another `Y` if it has a foreign key `y_id` pointing to `Y.id`. Since `Operator` has a key `contact_id` pointing to `Contact.id`, `Operator` **belongsTo** `Contact`. `Contact` does not have a `operator_id` key (I assumed so), so `Contact` does not **belongsTo** `Operator`, but `Contact` may **hasOne** or **hasMany** `Operator`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`hasOne` relationship only serves if you have `1 to 1` association to be able to access the associated model within the model which has no foreign key.

## belongsTo

In your case, you want to use `belongsTo`, `belongsTo` is used as soon as you have a foreign key in your model pointing to another model, your `Operator` model has foreign keys pointing to `Contact`, `Address`, `Land` which are resp. `contact_id`, `address_id` and `land_id`.

Since the `contact_id` field is in the `Operator` model, then the `Operator` model **belongsTo** the `Contact` model.

```php
class Operator extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array('Contact') ;
}
```

When fetching an `Operator` entry, you will get something like:

```
Array(
    [Operator] => Array
        (
            [id] => 42,
            [name] => 'operator',
            [contact_id] => 33
        )
    [Contact] => Array
        (
            [id] => 33,
            [name] => 'contact'
        )
)
```

## hasOne and hasMany

Since your `Operator` **belongsTo** `Contact`, your `Contact` **hasOne** *OR* **hasMany** `Operator`. Let's illustrate the difference between the two:

1. Each of your `Contact` entry is associated to only **one** `Operator`, you could add a `operator_id` foreign key inside your `Contact` model but it would be redundant because you already have the association using `contact_id` in `Operator`. Thus, what you do is create a **hasOne** association inside the `Contact` model, so `Contact` **hasOne** `Operator`.

```php
class Contact extends AppModel {
    public $hasOne = array('Operator') ;
}
```

Again, when fetching a `Contact` entry you will get:

```
Array(
    [Contact] => Array
        (
            [id] => 33,
            [name] => 'contact'
        )
    [Operator] => Array
        (
            [id] => 42,
            [name] => 'operator',
            [contact_id] => 33
        )
)
```

Note that this is the same as when fecthing an `Operator` with a **belongsTo** `Contact`. The difference between `hasOne` and `belongsTo` is mainly which model has a foreign key pointing to the other.

2. Eah of your `Contact` entry is associated to **multiple** (**many**) `Operator`, in this case your `Contact` **hasMany** `Operator`.

```php
class Contact extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array('Operator') ;
}
```

Again, the output of `$this->Contact->find()`:

```
Array(
    [Contact] => Array
        (
            [id] => 33,
            [name] => 'contact'
        )
    [Operator] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 42,
                    [name] => 'operator 42',
                    [contact_id] => 33
                )
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 47,
                    [name] => 'operator 47',
                    [contact_id] => 33
                )
        )
)
```

## hasAndBelongsToMany

Now, assume one `Operator` can have multiple `Contact`, and one `Contact` can serve multiple `Operator`. In this case, you need an extra table (which should be called `operators_contacts` if you follow CakePHP naming convention), with two fields `operator_id` and `contact_id`:

```php
class Contact extends AppModel {
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('Operator') ;
}
```

```php
class Operator extends AppModel {
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('Contact') ;
}
```

The output of `$this->Contact->find('all')` will be similar to the one using the **hasMany** relationship, main difference would be that their is no `operator_id` or `contact_id` field in the model.

---

## Full example

Let's assume I have the following models: `Company`, `Employee`, `Address`, and the following constraints:

- A `Company` has various `Employee` but only one `CEO` which is part of its `Employee`
- A `Company` has one `Address`, and there is at most one company at each `Address`

You have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE companies (
    id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ceo_id INTEGER REFERENCES employees (id)
) ;

CREATE TABLE employees (
    id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    company_id INTEGER REFERENCES companies (id)
) ;

CREATE TABLE addresses (
    id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    company_id INTEGER REFERENCES companies (id)
) ;
```

*Note that in this case, you cannot the table with all the constraints because you have a loop between `companies` and `employees`, you need to add the constraints after.*

And the following CakePHP models:

```php
class Company extends AppModel {

    /* A Company has many Employee. */
    public $hasMany = array('Employee') ;

    /* A Company has one CEO, but the key is in the Company model, 
       so it is a belongsTo relationship. */
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'CEO' => array(
            'className' => 'Employee', // It's an Employee
            'foreignKey' => 'ceo_id'
        )
    ) ;

    /* A Company has one address. */
    public $hasOne = array('Address') ; 

} ;
```

```php
class Employee extends AppModel {

    /* An Employee belongs to a Company. */
    public $belongsTo = array('Company') ;

} ;
```

```php
class Address extends AppModel {

    /* An address belongs to a Company. */
    public $belongsTo = array('Company') ;

} ;
```

Notice I have put a `company_id` foreign key in the `Address` model, so `Address belongsTo Company` and `Company hasOne Address`, I could have put a `address_id` inside the `Company` model and I would have had `Company belongsTo Address` and `Address hasOne Company`. I made an arbitrary choice here, in a real application you should think of which of the two above cases is the most meaningful.

Also note that the way I defined my model, there is nothing that prevent an `Employee` to be the `CEO` of a `Company` without being one of its own `Employee`.

---

You can find more information in [the CakePHP 2.x Book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html).

Comment: This is by far the best explanation I found in the web. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

you should you use `$belongsTo` instead of `hasOne` relationship for this purpose.

```
public $belongsTo = array(
        'Contact' => array(
            'className' => 'Contact',
            'foreignKey' => 'contact_id',   // check this
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'counterCache' => true
        )
    );
```

Comment: Since OP followed CakePHP naming convention, you can simply do `public $belongsTo = array('Contact') ;`.

Answer (score 1):

### Operator belongsTo xyz, not hasOne

`hasOne` and `belongsTo` associations are similar, but not the same. To illustrate the difference consider the following schema:

```
users
    id (int)
    name (string)

addresses
    id (int)
    user_id (int)
    is_home (bool)
    ... other fields ...
```

With `User` and `Address` models. Let's assume that there is only one "home" address per user, but a user is able to create multiple address records.

`belongsTo` means the table has a foreign key field in it (`addresses.user_id`) `has*` associations mean the *other* table has the foreign key (there is no `users.address_id`, User does not belongTo Address).

In summary, these statements would describe the model associations:

- User **hasMany** Addresses
- User **hasOne** *home* Address
- Address **belongsTo** User